Question with picture where people's faces are visible in very low resolution
This question contains a picture where people's faces are visible in very low resolution:
Software or web app to find the source of an animated GIF
Is it OK or not?
Someone flagged it with the comment below, but I have no strong opinion on the matter.

Picture of persons. Maybe a weapon been pointed at the camera?!


Good question Nicolas.
I don't know if there is a definitive answer, but the image wasn't helping improve the question in any way.  Consequently, given your valid concern, and the concern of the community member flagging the question, I decided to remove the image from the question.
The question itself isn't the highest quality question, but it's clear, focused, and understandable, so I think the question itself can remain.
